# How to fix domain with 301 redirect showing up on google results page?

Tags: redirect, search

I have a ".com.br" with a 301 redirect pointing to a ".com" domain, but the ".com.br" domain is showing up on google search results (SEPR). How can I remove the ".com.br" domain from google? Since it's a 301 redirect, was it suppoused to show up on results?

I am afraid that this ".com.br" domain is creating self-competition with my main domain (.com)
My search engine traffic is going down.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you setup a 301 redirect recently?

Comment: It's been around 2 weeks.

Comment: If the Redirect is `301` then you don't need to worry. Google or other search engines will handle it. It takes some times for search engines to update their database with the new domain.

Comment: Thank you, Amit. I'll wait, then =)

Comment: You are welcome Aline!